# Displaying overlaping polygons and popups in the qgis2web plugin?

Tags: qgis, polygon, popup, qgis2web

I'm total noobie when it comes to using qgis2web, CSS and HTML. The issue I'm having is displaying overlapping multipart polygons within the same shapefile (some of which are the same shape, but with different attribute data). In QGIS I have ordered the polygons to appear with the largest polygons at the bottom and the smallest towards the top. Some of the polygons do not appear at all. Where the polygons are the same shape it is difficult to tell if they have all come through, but only a single popup appears with one set of attribute data.

I have looked for answers on here, and I found this one: [How can I get a QGIS2Web project to display info for multiple layers in a popup?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/202393/how-can-i-get-a-qgis2web-project-to-display-info-for-multiple-layers-in-a-popup) but when I applied the code (which may have been in the wrong section), it stopped anything displaying at all from the qgis2web files.

I'm using QGIS 2.18.11 to create the shapefiles and qgis2web 2.22.0 to create the webmapping for wordpress.org.

Comment: Are you exporting the map as Leaflet or OpenLayers (bottom-left of the qgis2web dialog box)?

Comment: I have been using OpenLayers - I have had no success with exporting as Leaflet.

Comment: Is there any way I could send you the data @Tom Chadwin?