# Having qgis2web display info in popup for overlapping layers or overlapping features in layer

Tags: qgis, popup, qgis2web

This is my first venture into webmaps. I have a project that I am trying to export with qgis2web Leaflet option. I have a layer with overlapping polygons, and I would like for the info popup to display all the features.

Right now if you click on an area that I know has about 5 features, it will only show one, probably the top layer?

Ideally it would be something more like what QGIS does when you click info over multiple features.

[image: What it looks like now]

[image: What I'm hoping to achieve]

I found [Getting QGIS2Web project to display info for multiple layers in popup](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/202393) from 2016 that looks like a similar question, but the solution doesn't seem to be relevant anymore and lists folders that I don't have.